# What's the origin of words ending in the letter "j"?

Tags: etimología, ortografía

- What's the origin/etymology of these words? The only one that I know and it is common is `reloj`.
- Are there any others recognized by the RAE?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

["Reloj"](http://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/reloj) originally comes from latin "horologium".

I've read that the "j" ending is a result of Catalan "relotge".

I can think of another word ending in "j", ["carcaj"](http://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/carcaj) which means "quiver", as in the container used to carry arrows. Apparently this comes from French "carcais".

In [this website](http://etimologias.dechile.net/?carcaj) they list some words ending in "j" although I would say only "reloj" and "carcaj" are actually used.

Comment: From that list, **Boj** is also quite known, at least in Spain because there is a quite famous novel called "Madera de boj" written by the very well-known writer "Camilo José Cela". I agree the rest are unused (at least I have never seen or heard of any.)

Comment: I agree. Reloj, boj and carcaj are the only ones I've ever heard from that list.

Comment: Esto es tramposo, ya o sé, pero habría que agregar estas dos palabras son muy usadas: _contrarreloj_ y _puaj_.

Answer (score 6):

There are few words in Spanish that end with "J", and some of them are derivations of foreign origin: reloj (Greek "ωρολογιον"), boj (Catalan "boix"), carcaj (Greek "καρκάσιον"). There are other rarely used examples.

One thing you should keep in mind: the pronunciation of the letter "J" has changed through the passage of time. These are the phonetic representations of "J" in Spanish:

- medieval Spanish => /ž/
- during XV century => /š/
- from XVI - XVIII century => /x/ (south) /š/ (rest of the Iberian peninsula)
- since XIX century => /x/

But there are also regional differences and it isn't uncommon to find places where it sounds like an aspirated "h" or /h/.

In Spanish the word "reloj" was originally "reloje" or "reloxe", but later the "e" was dropped and the words "reloj" or "relox" appeared.

Another example of two words that still coexist is the name "Jimena", that is often found as "Ximena", towns like "Xixona" or "Jijona" (the first in Valencian), etc.

Comment: ¡Bienvenido a Spanish.SE! He hecho algunos cambios en tu post pero no estoy segura de haber entendido lo que querías decir en algunas ocasiones. Puedes comprobar los cambios pulsando *edited* sobre mi nombre.

Comment: Thanks... problems with English (not even my second language)

Answer (score 6):

There are fewer than 30 words ending in *-j* in Spanish, most of which were inherited from Arabic at a time when *j* in Spanish represented `/ʃ/` (i.e. the English sound 'sh'). The rest come from a variety of different origins:

#### Arabic

| word | alt. orthography | etymology |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [***alioj***](http://dle.rae.es/?id=1sWwe3j) |  | <sub>Hisp. Arabic</sub> *yašb* ← <sub>Aramaic</sub> *yašpe* ← <sub>Acadian</sub> *[j]ašpū* ("jaspe") |
| [***almiraj***](https://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/almiraj) |  | <sub>Arabic</sub> المعراج (*mi'raj*) |
| [***almofrej***](https://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/almofrej) |  | <sub>Arabic</sub> ﺍﻞﻣﻔﺭﺺ (*almafráš*) |
| [***almoraduj***](http://dle.rae.es/?id=20Ofqqj) | *almoradux* | <sub>Hisp. Arabic</sub> *almarda[d]dúš* ← <sub>Arabic</sub> *marzanǧūš* ← <sub>Greek</sub> ἀμάρακος |
| [***erraj***](https://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/erraj) | *herraj* | <sub>Hisp. Arabic</sub> ﺍﺭﻎ (*arráhǧ*, "polvo") |
| [***balaj***](https://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/balaj) | *balaje* | <sub>Arabic</sub> ﺑﻠﺨﺸﻲ (*balaẖš* ← *balaẖšī*, "badajshaní") |
| [***borraj***](https://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/borraj) | *bórax* | <sub>Arabic</sub> ﺑﻭﺭﻖ (*bawraq*) ← <sub>Persian</sub> *bure* |
| [***cambuj***](https://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/cambuj) | *gambuj*, *gambux*, *gambox* | <sub>Hisp. Arabic</sub> ﻛﻨﺒﺶ (*kanbúš*, "capuchón") ← <sub>Late Latin</sub> *caputium* |

#### Latin and apocopy of Old Spanish verbs

| word | alt. orthography | etymology |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [***dij***](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Dli4ffc) | *dije* | ? <sub>Latin</sub> [*dĭgĭtus*](https://definiciona.com/dij-o-dije/) `uncertain` |
| [***relej***](https://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/relej) | *releje* | *relejar* |
| [***rebalaj***](https://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/rebalaj) | *rebalaje* | *resbalar* |
| [***pedicoj***](https://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/pedicoj) |  | <sub>Latin</sub> *pes*, *pedis* ("pie") + *cojo* |
| [***maniblaj***](http://dle.rae.es/?id=ODHeswC) |  | ? `uncertain` |

#### French and Gothic

| word | alt. orthography | etymology |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [***troj***](https://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/troj) | *troja*, *troje* | ? <sub>Gothic</sub> [*thraughs*](http://etimologias.dechile.net/?troj) ("arca") `uncertain` |
| [***carcaj***](https://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/carcaj) | *carcax* | <sub>Old French</sub> *carcais* ← <sub>Byzantine Greek</sub> καρκάσιον (*karkásion*) |
| [***gambaj***](https://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/gambaj) | *gambax* | <sub>Old French</sub> *gambais* ← <sub>Gothic</sub> (*wamba*, "vientre") |

#### Catalan and Aragonese

| word | alt. orthography | etymology |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [***boj***](https://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/boj) | *boje* | *box* ← <sub>Catalan/Aragonese</sub> *boix* ← <sub>Latin</sub> *buxus*<sup>2</sup> |
| [***reloj***, ***contrarreloj***](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/reloj#Spanish) |  | <sub>Old Catalan</sub> *relotge* ← *orollotge* ← <sub>Latin</sub> *hōrologium* ← <sub>Ancient Greek</sub> ὡρολόγιον (*hōrológion*)<sup>3 4</sup> |

#### Onomatopoeia

| word | alt. orthography | etymology |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [***aj***](https://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/aj) | *ax*, *aje* |  | [*ax*](http://buscon.rae.es/drae/srv/search?type=3&val=aj) |
| [***puaj***](https://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/puaj) |  | — (compare with French *¡pouah!*) |  |

#### Foreign religious terms

| word | alt. orthography | etymology |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [***Aj***](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aj_(mitolog%C3%ADa)) |  | <sub>Egyptian</sub> Ꜣḫ (*Akh*) |
| [***sij***](https://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/sij) |  | <sub>English</sub> *Sikh* ← <sub>Punjabi</sub> ਸਿੱਖ (*sikkh*) ← <sub>Sanskrit</sub> *šisya*<sup>1</sup> |
| [***Pésaj***](https://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/P%C3%A9saj) |  | <sub>Hebrew</sub> פֶּסַח (*pésach*, "salto") |

#### American peoples

| word | alt. orthography | etymology |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [***chuj***](http://dle.rae.es/?id=92qzUVG) |  | Spanish [exonym](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chuj_people#Ethonym) for the Chuj people, language |
| [***itzaj***](http://dle.rae.es/?id=MEiuwXC) | *itzá*, *Itza'* |  |

All of these (with the exception of *Aj*, *almiraj*, *gambaj*, *rebalaj*, *Pésaj*, and *puaj*) have entries in the RAE, and 11 of them have alternate forms with a terminal *-je* or *-x*.

---

**Notes:**

1. <sub>The RAE introduced this orthography by analogy with other transliterations of the group *kh*, corresponding to words of Slavic origin so transcribed in English. However, in Punjabi the sound of the word does not correspond to `/x/`, being on the contrary much closer to `/k/`, and the choice is therefore deceptive and unjustified etymologically; Much more reasonable alternatives are *sik* or simply *sikh*.</sub>
2. <sub>*ix* is pronounced `/ʃ/` in (Eastern) Catalan, and when this word was first loaned to Spanish the letter *j* represented the same sound.</sub>
3. <sub>The current form of the word may partly be a back-formation of *relojes*, plural of obsolete *reloje*, which better conforms with the Catalan source and would explain the final *"j"*, which is rare in Spanish.</sub>
4. <sub>Compare with:</sub>
     <sub>• [*follaje*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/follaje#Spanish) from Occitan *follatge*</sub>
     <sub>• [*peaje*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/peaje#Spanish) from Catalan *peatge* or French *péage*</sub>
     <sub>• [*lenguaje*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/lenguaje#Spanish) from Old Spanish *lenguage*, borrowed from Old French *language* or Old Occitan *lenguatge*, *lengaje*</sub>
     • [*metraje*](https://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/metraje), [*fuselaje*](https://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/fuselaje), [*sabotaje*](https://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/sabotaje), [*paisaje*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/paisaje#Spanish) from French *métrage*,
   *fuselage*, *paysage* (comp. Catalan *paisatge* |