# When did "x" start representing /ks/ in Spanish again?

Tags: historia, pronunciación, latín, fonología

If I've understood correctly, Spanish phonology underwent this change from Latin with respect to the sound `/ks/`:

```
⟨x⟩ /ks/  →  ⟨x⟩ /ʃ/  →  ⟨x⟩ /ʃ/ ↘  
                                 ⟨j⟩ /x/
    ...  →  ⟨j⟩ /ʒ/  →  ⟨j⟩ /ʃ/ ↗
```

However there are a number of Spanish words that are spelled with an *x*, and pronounced as `/ks/` (realised as `[ks]`, `[gs]` or `[s]`, depending on context and register):

- *exacto* (**<sub><sup>EXACTUS</sup></sub>**)    vs *fijar* (**<sub><sup>FIXUS</sup></sub>**)
- *exento* (**<sub><sup>EXEMPTUS</sup></sub>**)   vs *ejercicio* (**<sub><sup>EXERCITIUM</sup></sub>**)
- *exhibir* (**<sub><sup>EXIBERE</sup></sub>**)    vs *mejilla* (**<sub><sup>MAXILLA</sup></sub>**)
- *exhortar* (**<sub><sup>EXHORTARI</sup></sub>**) vs *lejos* (**<sub><sup>LAXIUS</sup></sub>**)
- *exultar* (**<sub><sup>EXSULTO</sup></sub>**)    vs *lujuria* (**<sub><sup>LUXUS</sup></sub>**)

Some *x* words even have doublets spelled and pronounced as *j* `/x/`:

- (**<sub><sup>TEXERE</sup></sub>**) *textil, texto, textura        | tejer, tejido*
- (**<sub><sup>LAXARE</sup></sub>**) *laxitud, laxante           | dejar, dejadez*
- (**<sub><sup>COXINUM</sup></sub>**) *coxal                   | cojín*
- (**<sub><sup>ANNEXUS</sup></sub>**) *anexo, anexar, anexionar | anejo, anejar*
- (**<sub><sup>PROXIMUS</sup></sub>**) *próximo                | prójimo*

I imagine these words might have retained the *x* spelling due to very popular use, or them being borrowed as learned Latin words and not 'naturally' inherited into the language (e.g. *axón*), but:

Why (and when) did these words retain (or regain) their `/ks/` **pronunciation** when in most similar words it was lost?

---

<sup>**Examples:** [*Spanish Vocabulary: An Etymological Approach*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=VAzIqcTqe54C&pg=PA190&dq=spanish+when+did+x+represent+"ks"), David Brodsky</sup>

Comment: The pairs like próximo/prójimo generally are a natural evolution (prójimo) along with a reimport from Latin that occurred after the sound change(s) were no longer productive. In almost all cases I can think of, the pairs end up with different, albeit related, uses (probably the easiest to see this in is lugar/local. Notice the /ks/ sound was preserved with the prefix *ex-* and before consonants. Intervocalically is where the shifts happened.) The date of reimport will be different for each word, but obviously necessarily will be after the sound changes were no longer productive.

Comment: The letter X has had multiple pronunciations since at least the first orthography, the spelling change was really more to represent /x/ with **j** and retain **x** for /ks/, rather than to get rid of X.

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking for, do you want to know when the "X" represented a the "KS" sound or when words with "x" started to be pronounced like "KS" ?

Comment: (Assuming these words spelled with an __x__ were at one time *not* pronounced like /ks/) I would like to know when words spelled with an __x__ started being pronounced /ks/.

Comment: @guifa `"Notice the /ks/ sound was preserved with the prefix ex- and before consonants."` This doesn't seem to be completely true. See, for example, *ejercicio, ejemplo, ejecutar* whose older orthographies were *exercicio, exemplo, executar*. `"The letter X has had multiple pronunciations since at least the first orthography"` Do you have a source for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As guifa says in a comment, the sound change of /ks/ to /x/ was blocked when the letter *x* was followed by a consonant. In these circumstances /ks/ was generally reduced to /s/, with the /ks/ pronunciation re-emerging as a form of hypercorrection:

> ## -*X*-
>
> The evidence indicates that this Latin letter represented [ks]. The development of the sound in Vulgar Latin and in the Romance languages varied from region to region, with more changes occurring in Spanish than in any other case.
>
> In Castilian territory the [ks] > [js] > [sj] > [š]. This last phone leveled with [ž] from Latin J and G (e, i) in the fifteenth and sixteenth centuries, and the resulting [š] gradually became [χ] by 1650. In the nineteenth century the Spanish Royal Academy did away with the spelling *x*, except in Latinisms such as *examen, sexta,* and words such as *dixe* are now spelled with *j* (*dije*). In Mexico, especially, the *x* has been retained in words of Indian origin to represent a primitive [š] (Mexico, Xalapa, Oaxaca), now [χ], and in Yucatan one still hears the [š] (Uxmal) among the Maya- speaking inhabitants or among foreigners ...
>
> ...
>
> **It is to be noted that the evolution of X to an ultimate [χ] did not take place when it was supported by a consonant** as in FRÁX(I)NU > *fresno*, SÉXTA > *siesta*, **and where X has been retained before a consonant, generally represents [s]** (*extraño* [estráño], *experiencia* [esperjénsja]).<sup>135</sup>
>
> In the other Romance languages the -X- [ks] usually became a sibilant or retained its original Latin value. In Catalan and Portuguese the descendents are [s] (*x*) and [s] (*ss*) and the letter X has been extended to represent [š] of other origins than Latin X:
>
> Arabic [š] (P. *xadrez* C. *aixedres*), Latin -PS- (P. C. *caixa*). In Catalan the [č] is represented normally by *tx*.<sup>136</sup>
>
> <sup>**135. In the latter type [s] (= *x* preceding consonant), hypercorrection often produces [ks] or [gs] through pedantic school teaching, i.e. *sexta* [séksta] and *extrano* [ekstráno]. This is not the popular pronunciation however.**</sup>

- [*An Introduction to Romance Linguistics*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=1WZfAAAAMAAJ&dq=%22x%20ks%22), Delos Lincoln Canfield, John Cary Davis (p.92-93)

---

Thus, words with an 'x' spelling come under three categories in Spanish:

1. - **...xV...** <sub>(x followed by vowel, naturally inherited from Latin to Spanish)</sub>
     `⟨x⟩ /ks/  →  ⟨x⟩ [js]  →  ⟨x⟩ [sj]  →  ⟨x⟩ /ʃ/  →  ⟨j⟩ /ʃ/  →  ⟨j⟩ /x/`

     > e.g. *exemplus* → *exemplo* → *ejemplo*
   - **...x...** <sub>(loanword at time when "x" was pronounced `/ʃ/`)</sub>
     `⟨x⟩ /ʃ/  →  ⟨j/x⟩ /ʃ/  →  ⟨j/x⟩ /x/`

     > e.g. <sub>(Nahuatl: *[Mēxihco](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/23602/18348)*  →  )</sub> *México* → [*Méjico*](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/26627/18348) → [*México*](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/245/18348)
     >   e.g. <sub>(Catalán: *boxus*   →  *[boix](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/25539/18348)*  →  )</sub> *box* →  *boj*
2. **...xC...** <sub>(x followed by consonant, naturally inherited from Latin to Spanish)</sub>
   `⟨x⟩ /ks/  →  ⟨x⟩ [s]  →  ⟨x⟩ [ks]~[gs]~[s]`

   > e.g. *expertus* → *experto*
3. **...x...** <sub>(x, learned Latin borrowing)</sub>
   `⟨x⟩ /ks/  →  ⟨x⟩ [ks]~[gs]~[s]`

   > e.g. *proximus* → *próximo*